# android combination of autocomplete and spinner with countries list

Tags: android

I have a list of countries from which the user should choose. 
I can show them in a spinner, but the user must scroll and scroll (the list contains about 200 countries)
I can use autocomplete, this will shorten the number of entries significantly, but the user could still input something completely different.
How to make some combination which on one hand shortens the number of elements in the drop-down, and on the other hand prevents the user from inputting something illegal?

I was thinking of having an edittext and then interrupt the user-input after she has typed 2 or 3 characters and then show a spinner instead. But

1. i dont know how to do that interrupt and
2. it seems much too complex

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something to identify the users language, or ip and go from there.